# Sms Messages not Loading into ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, smsmanager

I am working on an android project and I am stuck getting the SMS messages to load into the app. This is thew error I am encountering:
[image]

I am trying to setup a list view and using an Array Adapter in this piece of code:

**SMS INBOX**

```
    private fun fetchInbox(): ArrayList<String> {
    val sms: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    val uri: Uri = Uri.parse("contact://sms/inbox")
    val cursor: Cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, arrayOf("id", "address", "date", "body"), null, null, null)

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){

        val address: String = cursor.getString(1)
        val body: String = cursor.getString(3)

        sms.add("Address: $address" + "Message: $body")
    }

    return sms


}
```

And then I am calling it in my MainActivity like this:

```
        val listView = text_Messages

    if(fetchInbox() != null) {

        val adapter: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, fetchInbox())
        listView.adapter = adapter


    }
```

I just don't understand why this error would occur

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
     ListView lViewSMS = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSMS);

            if(fetchInbox()!=null)
            {
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fetchInbox());
                lViewSMS.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
//put the above part in oncreateview()
        public ArrayList fetchInbox()
        {
            ArrayList sms = new ArrayList();

            Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body","" + "person"},null,null,null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while  (cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                String match="is created";
                String address = cursor.getString(1);
                String body = cursor.getString(3);
               // String title = cursor.getString(3);
                String tdata=body;
       sms.add(""+""+body);






            }
            return sms;

        }
```